# How to exclude the first column from jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function which enables hover event on a table. It currently excludes the 
header row but I also need it to exclude the very first column. Any ideas?

```
  $(".GridViewStyle > tbody > tr:not(:has(table, th))")                
                .mouseover(function(e) {
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".GridViewStyle > tbody > tr:not(:has(table, th)) td:not(:first-child)")
```

but you will have hover or mouseover fired for tds not trs. so in handler you'll do

```
$(this).closest('tr')
```

to access tr which you was going to change style etc

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
    $(".GridViewStyle > tbody > tr:not(:has(table, th)) td:not(:eq(0))")
```

Comment: it won't exclude first td in tr

Comment: sorry i edited it (you must select tds of course i didn't read well the question, i was excluding first row)